# Focus view or editor when click on it in eclipse rcp

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am new to RCP. I need same focus as we see in eclipse. if i click on any View or Editor, border should be highlighted or solid. Any steps or code would be appreciated.

Comment: It is the theme / CSS you are using that determines if this shown

Comment: Thanks Greg. It is done. How can I add themes into Preferences page ?

Comment: Look at the `IThemeEngine` interface.